# Passing a macro as a parameter in FreeMarker with its own parameters

Tags: freemarker

Some of my FreeMarker macros have parameters that accept other macros. This allows me to have a standard part of the page that can be changed on the odd occasion. In the example below, the article macro  will by default use the defaultHeader. Sometimes I use the alternativeHeader by passing the alternativeHeader macro as the header parameter. This works fine.

Sometimes I want to pass the alternativeHeader macro but changing its text parameter. The only way I know how to do this is to create another 'caller' macro and then use this. However, this means I would have to add these 'caller' macros to a lot of pages and they just look messy. Is there another way of passing the alternativeHeader macro directly while also setting its parameter?

```
<html>
    <head><title>test</title></head>
    <body>
        <@article body="First example"/>
        <@article body="Second example" header=alternativeHeader/>
        <@article body="Third example" header=alternativeHeaderCaller/>
    </body>
</html>

<#--
  These three macros would usually be contained in a library.
-->
<#macro article body header=defaultHeader>
    <div>
        <@header/>
        <br>
        ${body}
    </div>
</#macro>
<#macro defaultHeader>
    This is a default header
</#macro>
<#macro alternativeHeader text="This is an alternative header">
    ${text}
</#macro>

<#--
  I want to avoid having to add and use this macro.
-->
<#macro alternativeHeaderCaller>
    <@alternativeHeader text="I have changed this header"/>
</#macro>
```

Output

```
<html>
    <head><title>test</title></head>
    <body>
    <div>
    This is a default header
        <br>
        First example
    </div>
    <div>
    This is an alternative header
        <br>
        Second example
    </div>
    <div>
    I have changed this header
        <br>
        Third example
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm looking for something like this

```
<@article body="Third example" header=alternativeHeaderCaller(text="My other text")/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do anything better... there's no "currying" feature in FTL.